# JavaScript - Garbage collection after function calls

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I had some reads about garbage collection in JavaScript, according to them, local variables of functions are collected after the function returned ([except for the cyclical references](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_03.htm) that need breaking circles for the GC to work).

What I'm trying to understand is, what does "function returned" in this context mean?

Does it mean:

1. The function has to return values.

   or simply:
2. The function call has ended.

Common sense (according to me at least) suggests 2), but in the case I'm wrong:

- What about functions that don't return values?
- Should I add an empty `return;` to the functions that don't return anything to make the garbage collector do its job?

Comment: The language specification does not specify when garbage collection occurs. Implementations are free to do it whenever they want, as long as they never collect anything that is still accessible to the program. The article you link to discusses some *possible* ways it could be done, but there is no requirement that it be done any of those ways. That article is quite old and GC technology has changed a lot since it was originally written.

Comment: Re your link: This is 2013. I think it's safe to assume no one is using Netscape Navigator 3 :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functions that don't contain a `return` statement implicitly return `undefined`. So a function "ending" and "returning" are the same thing.

Concerning garbage collection, keep in mind that local variables are not collected *immediately* after functions return; they can just *become eligible* for garbage collection at that point. The garbage collector runs whenever the browser considers it *must* run, or believes it can run without affecting visible performance much (and that's implementation-dependent).

Comment: Great answer, upped and selected.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I was under the impression that there's also reference counting - so that in easy cases, it'll immediately collect unreferenced stuff.  Like x = [1,2,3]; x = null; the array memory can immediately be re-used.  The garbage collector need only run when circularly-connected structures fool the ref counting, and they collect up.

Comment: @OsamaBinLogin Most surely there is also reference counting, although implementations may vary. This answer was written with closures in mind, with local variables being closed over by a returned function object. After the outer function returns, handling that is up to GC, I believe.